# QTextEdit insert text

Tags: c++, qt

How to change content in QTextEdit while it has focus? If I try to change content while QTextEdit is focused, my program was terminated. If I use clearFocus(), nothing was changed.

```
connect(ui->myTextEdit,SIGNAL(textChanged()),this,SLOT(hTextChanged()));
.
.
.
void hTextChanged()
{
    ui->myTextEdit->insertPlainText("blah");
}
```

EDIT: I need change text (it's color) in QTextEdit while user continues in input, how to do it without textChanged() signal?.

Comment: you should post some code that reproduces your problem

Comment: Please post a full demo. Your snippet looks like an infinite loop by connecting a signal to a slot that causes the signal to be emitted. Is hTextChanged() actually a slot? Does connect() succeed?

Comment: hmm, you are right, I made recursion ... damn

Comment: Regarding the update: Do you mean the color of the entire text or only the color of the typed characters?

Comment: color of typed characters, I need to color diferent tags with diferent color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your snippet looks like an infinite loop by connecting a signal to a slot that causes the signal to be emitted.

Regarding your update: 
For coloring the text use a QSyntaxHighlighter object (see Qt documentation).